# confusion over the phrase "extend Object.prototype or one of the other build-in prototype"

Tags: javascript, prototype, encapsulation

I'm currently studying javascript prototype and inheritance, and I have encountered the following paragraphs on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain)

I'm not exactly sure what the author meant by `extend Object.prototype or one of the other build-in prototype`. Could someone please clarify the concept, preferably with a code sample? Thanks

[image]

Comment: It basically means *"try not to add anything to `Object.prototype`"*. For instance `Object.prototype.buyMeAPony = function() { ... }` would be a bad idea. Same goes for other built-in prototypes

Comment: oh yes, that makes sense. thank you for the comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term "*built-in prototype*" refers to the prototype objects from which standard objects inherit. This includes the language-specified `Boolean.prototype`, `Number.prototype`, `String.prototype`, `Symbol.prototype`, `Object.prototype`, `Array.prototype`, `Function.prototype`, `Date.prototype`, and the prototype objects for the various `Error`s, typed arrays, data structures ((Weak-) Map, Set) and iterators.

It also encompasses other native prototype objects in the environment, for example the DOM (`Node.prototype`, `Element.prototype`, `Document.prototype`, …) and other Web APIs (e.g. `XMLHttpRequest.prototype`).

See the [definition of *built-in objects*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-built-in-object) and the [whole section about *standard built-in objects*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ecmascript-standard-built-in-objects) in ES6.

In general, you should not mess with them. They are supplied by the environment, they are not yours - don't touch them and create your own methods on them. If you want to write modular, interoperable code, you should not depend on custom, global modifications of built-ins. See also [Why is extending native objects a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14034180/1048572) for more discussion.

Answer (score 1):

Other things besides `Object`, such as `Array` and `Function`, have prototypes too.  It's considered bad practice to extend those prototypes as well, for the reasons mentioned on MDN.